# NSPredicate - Unable to parse the format string

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to write a `NSPredicate` to fetch rows with my_column value with this string "`193e00a75148b4006a451452c618ccec`" and I get the below crash.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "my_column=193e00a75148b4006a451452c618ccec"'

My predicate statement

```
fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@==\"%@\"",attributeName,itemValue]];
```

also tried this

```
fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ == %@",attributeName,itemValue]];
```

this

```
fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = %@",attributeName,itemValue]];
```

and this

```
fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=\"%@\"",attributeName,itemValue]];
```

Please help.

**I found out this, when I was trying with Martin R's answer**

```
fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@==%@",attributeName,itemValue];
```

**attributeName I pass comes with a ' ' so I took off attributeName and hardcoded it, then it works fine.**

Comment: make use of LIKE instead of '='  if you are comparing strings!

Comment: There is no need for quotes when you are using a placeholder.

Comment: @VinayakKini: One should not generally use "LIKE" for comparing strings, because LIKE does a wildcard matching where "*" and "?" have a special meaning.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Enclose the string in single quotes:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"my_column = '193e00a75148b4006a451452c618ccec'"]
```

or *better*, use argument substitution:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"my_column = %@", @"193e00a75148b4006a451452c618ccec"]
```

The second method avoids problems if the search string contains special characters
such as `'` or `"`.

*Remark:* Never use `stringWithFormat` when building predicates. `stringWithFormat` and
`predicateWithFormat` handle the `%K` and `%@` format differently, so combining these
two methods is very error-prone (and unnecessary).

Comment: I tried both already, no effect.

Comment: @satheeshwaran: Never use `stringWithFormat` when building predicates!!! Please try it exactly as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Hey @Martin R I also did that, no use :-(.

Comment: @satheeshwaran: Please show the exact code that your tried.

Comment: I have posted all the code I tried above.

Comment: @satheeshwaran: But you have not tried what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: I did not post, but I tried it. I found the issue.

Comment: I use NSStringWithFormat first, and then in the predicate, for me it is the best method. No others were working.

Comment: You are a god sir. Or well, a dog. Dog god. Whatever, amazingly helpful answer!

Comment: The single quotes did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have missed '' when checking for equality,

now try,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"my_column='193e00a75148b4006a451452c618ccec'"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
//Case Insensitive
fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = [cd] %@",attributeName,itemValue];

//Case sensitive
fetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@",attributeName,itemValue];
```

Comment: 1) Note that "LIKE" does a wildcard comparison where "*" and "?" have a special meaning! - 2) For a fixed attribute name it is not necessary to use `%K`.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for that info :). I just wanted to show that for an attribute the placeholder needs to be with %K. If using LIKE has got an issue, how can we do a case insensitive and diacritic search.

Comment: You can do `"my_column ==[cd] %@"` !

Comment: @MartinR Using %K for a fixed attribute name is necessary because the Core Data SQL generator otherwise has no way of knowing that the left side of the expression is a key path. It works without %K most of the time because Core Data tries to make educated guesses all the time.

Comment: @ChristianKienle Using %K would be more appropriate when a predicate is written for more generic use, here OP wanted to check for only a fixed attribute, that's what Martin's point was. I included it in my answer so that it would be useful for OP. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Anupdas IMHO you need %K always (at least in theory). The only reason why you don't need in in practice sometimes is because Core Data makes guesses. I know that because I wrote a NSIncrementalStore subclass which generates SQL from a NSPredicate and if you simply pass "attribute == value" as a predicate to Core Data then you have no way of knowing what "attribute" is. The left hand side of a expression can be anything. It does not always have to be a keypath. By using %K you actually get a keypath expression on the left hand side. Otherwise you get something else.

Comment: @ChristianKienle So are you saying that by including %K we are making the job easier for which ever function using predicate, since this avoids guesses ?

Comment: @Anupdas Don't get me wrong: This is a bit like splitting hair from my part. In 99% of the cases everything will be okay but yes: Using %K makes the job easier (and more robust) for everything/everyone that examines NSPredicates. You simply don't have to guess what the predicate might mean.

Comment: @ChristianKienle: I see your point. Most (all?) examples in the Apple documentation use inline attributes, and I have done so in my code, but it is correct that this can be ambiguous.

Comment: In Swift 3 , i was able to solve similar error with the format as below: fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = \"\(bookInfo.title)\"", [])