# Compound Predicate not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nspredicate

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfPredicates=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self.attendeeListSet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop){
    NSString *userId=[obj userId];
    [arrayOfPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %@",userId]];
}];
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:arrayOfPredicates];
[request setPredicate:compoundPredicate];
```

I am setting this compound predicate for multiple userIds in an array and i need to get the Users from those User ids using OR.

The above is not working but when I'm hardcoding using

```
 NSPredicate *predicate1=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(userID like[cd] %@) 
                            OR (userID like[cd] %@)",@"sheetal2", @"sheetal3"];  
[arrayOfPredicates addObject:predicate1];
```

Now this is working..Can anyboady tell  whats the problem with my code..

Thanks

Comment: This may sound silly, in the first one you are using userID and in the other you are suing eventID?

Comment: @Anupdas leave the IDs...what i ma saying is its not working...i just copy pasted..i have Editted

Comment: When you are posting question, leave no room for guess work. Even now your above query is case sensitive and second one is case insensitive?  And also log `arrayOfPredicates` to see their content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code the predicate uses `==`. In the second code the predicate uses `LIKE[cd]`. Because the `userID` is an `NSString`, using `LIKE` is generally a better way to tell the predicate to compare the values, but the real difference is that the second approach is case and diacritic insensitive and the first approach requires an exact match.

Comment: Can you please check the comments of MartinR on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16358617/767730). I think using of `LIKE` is not always the best.

Comment: Thanks @Anupdas, I've improved the answer and I never thought of doing '==[cd]' before, good information.

Comment: But i dont know why when i was hardcoding == was working as well